# define associate array without value

Tags: javascript

I have a very large hard coded index array that I would like to easily convert to an associative array so lookups are much quicker.

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
```

right now I am looping through arr and comparing it's values to a value to see if there is a match. Now that I have hundreds of elements it's getting rather slow and it would be faster to have an associative array.

It seems I can't just do

```
var arr = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

I can't really add a value since it is too slow.

Sure I could copy the elements to an associate array or sort the array and do a binary search but it would be much easier to just able to assign a default value to the array elements and use the syntax above.

I guess this is not possible though?

Comment: what does adding a value to an object property have to do with speed?

Comment: @thesystem If it's using a hash lookup, it can hash the key to find the bucket it's in, which should reduce the lookup space.

Comment: @alex: no, I was referring to this: *"I can't really add a value since it is too slow."*

Comment: How are you creating your array?

Comment: I said they are hard coded, manually, and already exist, I'd have to manually add all values by hand(I could use a search and replace but still slow). I'd have to add the values by hand to all the keys I've added. I am not using the values. Just the keys for O(1) lookup.

Comment: @jsmdnq Have you found a solution?

Comment: @ATOzTOA yes, I simply create a duplicate of the index array into an associative array and use the associative array. I still enter the values as normal. It wastes space but at least is fast to manually enter in the elements and fast to search.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mapLookup = arr.reduce(function (accumalator, value) {
    accumalator[value] = true;
    return accumalator;
}, {});
```

Comment: IE 8 doesn't support reduce, and it's still fairly prevalent

Answer (score 1):

Why not:
    var arr = {"a":1, "b":1, "c":1};

Comment: because I'd have to add `:1` to about 1000 + elements and to every element I manually added to the array.

Answer (score 1):

Most modern browsers support `Array.indexOf()`. This will return `-1` if your search bears no results.

Are you actually having speed issues, or are you just pre-optimizing? The container you should be using is an array. You have an array of elements - they don't associate with any other values, so why put them in a map container?

Also, it sounds like you want a `set`, where you have a *unique* set of elements.

Comment: OP wants to compare against the value, not the a,b,c keys.

Comment: Yes, I have speed issues, I've fixed them by converting my arrays to associative arrays and it's about 1000 times faster now. (instant)

Answer (score 1):

Converting arrays to associative arrays seems to be the easiest and very fast:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c"];
var arrA = {}; for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) arrA[arr[i]] = 0;
```

then just use `key in arrA` for O(1) lookup. (it would be easier to have the ability not have to explicitly supply a value to a key but....)

Essentially

```
if (key in arrA) ...
```

replaces

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) if (key == arr[i]) ...
```

which essentially is O(n) vs O(n^2) when uses inside a loop.

Comment: If you really want to shorten it, you could do `eval("({" + arr.join(":1,") + ":1})")`